# detect a continuous press on View

Tags: android

I need to play a certain sound as long as the user holds an `ImageView` pressed and pause it when the user stop holding it. Before doing anything with the `MediaPlayer`, I tried to test it with a `Vibrator`(please don't laugh at this point) object. I've implemented and set an `OnTouchListener`:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        vib.vibrate(50);

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        /*--- no action required ---*/
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        vib.cancel();
        break;
    }
    return false;

}
```

However, the vibrate action is only performed once, no matter how long I hold the `ImageView` pressed. I guess a `MediaPlayer` will react the same way. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. the press is detected correctly, because the `Vibrator` logs "cancel()" only after I release my finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stop because in function

```
vib.vibrate(50);
```

you set to 50 ms time in vibration [check](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)

```
void vibrate(long milliseconds)
Vibrate constantly for the specified period of time.
```

I think rest of your code is correct.

Comment: oh, thanks. My fail. Somehow I did assume it will repeat the action until the View is released from press.